# Is there a way to use one native-base theme across multiple react-native apps?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I'm working on a project that has a single backend, and multiple front-end apps in `react-native`.

I would like to use one theme across all of these `react-native` apps to keep branding/etc on point.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

I tried a symlink from one app to another's `native-base-theme` folder, but that didn't work.

I'm using Expo for the apps, and after digging through some issue threads it turns out Metro bundler doesn't follow symlinks?
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18725#issuecomment-380268250

I also tried to just move the `native-base-theme` folder to a parent directory of both apps and import the theme modules that way.

Both ways (symlink and parent dir) gave these errors:

```
Unable to resolve module './native-base-theme/components' from '/Users/me/workspace/my-app/App.js'
The module './native-base-theme/components' could not be found from '/Users/me/workspace/my-app/App.js'
Indeed, none of these files exist:
    '/Users/me/workspace/my-app/native-base-theme/components(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    '/Users/me/workspace/my-app/native-base-theme/components/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

`/Users/me/workspace/my-app/native-base-theme/components/index.js` does actually exist there.

with symlink:

```
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
import platform from './native-base-theme/variables/platform';
```

with parent directory:

```
import getTheme from '../native-base-theme/components';
import platform from '../native-base-theme/variables/platform';
```

also tried just for the heckin of it:

```
import getTheme from '../native-base-theme/components/index';
```

and

```
import getTheme from '../native-base-theme/components/index.js';
import platform from '../native-base-theme/variables/platform.js';
```

I'm importing the same way that works, in accordance with the docs, after ejecting the native-base theme with `node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js`

I expect (hope?) to use one single `native-base-theme` folder for multiple apps in order to maintain consistency in the theming across all apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this thanks to the awesome folks in this issue thread:
https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1#issuecomment-462981541

That link should go straight to my post of how I solved this issue.

I will post the paste below if you dont want to navigate to the issue thread, though some of the other posts in that thread definitely good insight.

---

@th317erd I was able to get it work! Thanks a ton!

the watcher is also working like a charm! When I change anything in the theme folder, the expo app will reload on my phone  very awesome.

My structure looks like this (*only showing important files*):
`my-app/` and `themes/` are in the same directory.

```
/User/me/workspace/my-project/
      |
      +--my-app/
            |
            +-- App.js
            +-- package.json
            +-- rn-cli-config.js
            +-- (etc project files)
      |
      +--themes/
            |
            +-- native-base-theme
                  |
                  +-- components
                        |
                        +-- index.js (compiles everything to one export)
                        +-- package.json (created with 'npm init')
                  |
                  +-- variables
                        |
                        +-- platform.js (exports theme variables I am using/modifying)
                        +-- package.json (created with 'npm init')
```

`themes/native-base-theme/components/package.json`:
*set entry point to `index.js` by setting `"main"` key.*

```
{
  "name": "custom-theme-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "custom-theme-components",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`themes/native-base-theme/variables/package.json`:
*set entry point to `platform.js` by setting `"main"` key.*

```
{
  "name": "custom-theme-variables",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "custom-theme-variables",
  "main": "platform.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In `my-app`'s `package.json`:

```
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "custom-theme-components": "file:../themes/native-base-theme/components",
        "custom-theme-variables": "file:../themes/native-base-theme/variables",
    },
```

`App.js`:

```
import getTheme from 'custom-theme-components';
import variables from 'custom-theme-variables'
...
   render() {
      return (
         <Root>
           <StyleProvider style={getTheme(variables)}>
             <AppContainer />
           </StyleProvider>
         </Root>
       );
}
...
```

`rn-cli.config.js` pasted directly from @joerneu's comment on Jan 11:
https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1#issuecomment-453649261

I then had to do the four steps for the Haste modules common error before it would properly compile:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ rm -rf node_modules && npm install
$ rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*
$ rm -rf /temp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
```

after that `$ expo start` and it worked <3

I will probably go back and clean it up a bit. might just be able to combine those in to one nice module and remove one of the steps down in to the directory.